# Redis - prioritizing two sets of keys (eviction policy)

Tags: redis

We have two separate set of keys in **one** Redis instance (**set1** and **set2**). All keys in both sets have an expire time set.

If Redis instance hits max memory cap, we want keys from **set1** (and only from it!) be evicted to free some memory, but we need to have a guarantee that keys from **set2** will **not** be evicted until their time limit and, thus, will always expire in a normal way.

Is there any possibility to achieve it?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't provide this finely grained of a level of control over cache invalidation. You're restricted to the following options:

- **noeviction**: New values aren’t saved when memory limit is reached. When a database uses replication, this applies to the primary database
- **allkeys-lru**: Keeps most recently used keys; removes least recently used (LRU) keys
- **allkeys-lfu**: Keeps frequently used keys; removes least frequently used (LFU) keys
- **volatile-lru**: Removes least recently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- **volatile-lfu**: Removes least frequently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- **allkeys-random**: Randomly removes keys to make space for the new data added.
- **volatile-random**: Randomly removes keys with expire field set to true.
- **volatile-ttl**: Removes keys with expire field set to true and the shortest remaining time-to-live (TTL) value.

The best you could do would be to set the policy to *noeviction* and then write your own cache-invalidation process. Or maybe set it to *volatile-ttl* and then have **set2** be non-volatile keys that you remove manually. A fair bit of work and possibly not worth it.

The [documentation describing these options](https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) also provides some good insight into how Redis actually removes things and might be worth perusing.